# PostgreSQL set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE using JPA

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, sql-function

I have a sql function that looks like:

```
CREATE OR  replace FUNCTION search(IN word character VARYING) 
returns setof certificates AS $$SELECT c 
FROM   certificates c 
WHERE  Upper(description) LIKE Upper('%\'||word||'%') 
OR Upper(NAME) LIKE Upper('%\' 
              ||word 
              ||'%') $$ language sql;
```

And I'm trying to call it using JPA like:

```
SELECT c FROM Certificates c WHERE c in (function('search',:findPhrase ))
```

And I'm getting `set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE`
But if I change the return type of my sql function to just certificates instead of setof certificates it works. But it only finds 1 record.
I was trying different things including casting result to an array and using ids instead of whole objects. Nothing really helps.
So the question is: How to make my code work as desired?

I simplified my real case to just show the problematic part. The whole SQL looks more like:

```
SELECT c FROM Certificates 
JOIN c.tags t WHERE t.name IN :names "
"GROUP BY (c.id) "
"HAVING COUNT(c.id) >= :size
  AND c IN (function('search',:findPhrase ))
```

At the end i switched my TypedQuery to NativeQuery and used this code

```
AND c in(select search(:findPhrase))
```

So the whole SQL now looks like

```
SELECT * FROM certificates c JOIN certificate_tags ct ON c.id = ct.certificate_id JOIN tags t ON t.id = ct.tag_id WHERE t.name IN (?) GROUP BY (c.id, ct.id, t.id) HAVING COUNT(c.id) >= ? AND c in(select search(?))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `select` the set that the function returns. I think you just want:

```
select * from function('search',:findPhrase) c
```

Postgres even allows:

```
select function('search',:findPhrase) c
```

Comment: I tryed 
SELECT c FROM Certificates 
JOIN c.tags t WHERE t.name IN :names "
"GROUP BY (c.id) "
"HAVING COUNT(c.id) >= :size
  AND c IN ( select function('search',:findPhrase) )
But now it says: No data type for node

Comment: @DenisBahlei: this looks like a different problem. Please start by running that query as provided, and see if it works.

Comment: So i tryed to run this SELECT c FROM GiftCertificate c WHERE c in (select function('search',:findPhrase)) and i've got No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode